# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Loading local module causes errors

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ecmascript-6

I have the following in one of my Hapi.js routes:

`handler: require('./publishCallSheet')(server),`

This works locally, but when I deploy the code to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance, I always get this error: `Error: Cannot find module './publishCallSheet'`

The module is one of the first modules I've converted in my file to be es6 compatible, so not sure if that matters or not

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that on OSX, file name case sensitivity doesn't matter, on Unix, it does. The filename is `publishCallsheet` NOT `publishCallSheet`